# Box Dimension of Cantor Middle-Third Set

Tags: fractals, cantor-set

The calculation of the box dimension for the Cantor middle third set $C$ typically goes as such

> In the $n$th step of constructing $C$, there are $2^n$ line segments of length $\frac{1}{3^n}$ each remaining. 
> So, if we take $\epsilon_n = \frac{1}{3^n}$, then we get $N(\epsilon_n) = 2^n$, and thus
> \begin{equation}
> D_B = - \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{\log N(\epsilon)}{\log \epsilon} = \lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{\log 2^n}{\log 3^n} = \frac{\log 2}{\log 3}
> \end{equation}

My question arose when I decided to generalize this by taking $\epsilon_n = \frac{1}{3^{n+\delta(n)}}$ instead, for some $\delta(n) \in\mathbb{N}$. Then, we would get $N(\epsilon_n) = 2^n 3^{\delta(n)}$ (still an integer), and so
\begin{equation}
D_B = \lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{\log 2^n 3^{\delta(n)}}{\log 3^{n+\delta(n)}} = \frac{\log 2}{\log 3} \lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{n}{n+\delta(n)} +  \lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{\delta(n)}{n+\delta(n)}
\end{equation}

In this case, the limit depends on how $\delta(n)$ varies with $n$. But shouldn't the box dimension be independent of this? If so, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't your $N(\epsilon_n) = 2^n 3^{\delta(n)}$ be $N(\epsilon_n) = 2^n 2^{\delta(n)}$?

Comment: @MarkMcClure No, it shouldn't, as with your example the total length of the line segment left at each step would not be the same as the case for $\delta = 0$

Comment: Well, $N(1/3^n) = 2^n$ for *every* natural number $n$. Thus $N(1/3^{n+\delta(n)}) = 2^{n+\delta(n)}$, since $n+\delta(n)$ is a natural number.

Comment: The point is that you made your mistake when you wrote $N(\epsilon_n) = 2^n 3^{\delta(n)}$. If the above argument doesn't make sense to you, then you might want to make sure that you fully understand why $N(\epsilon_n) = 2^n$ when $\epsilon_n=1/3^n$ in the first place.